# Static public events

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a public static class, which has some public stuff I use across my informs project. Is it a good idea to add a public static event for Logout and Login events and register all concerned classes and forms to this event to minimize the code because currently I have a lot of code in the log out and login methods to handle forms and different classes upon logging in or out, instead I just fire the event at the login and log out methods and put code in the event handlers methods for each class registered for the event. Is this a good or bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

It's bad because your listener objects (those are bound to those static events) will never be garbage-collected and you should avoid static events at all. That's why Weak Event Pattern born. Although I am not saying that you need to use that pattern (because I am not well informed about your app internals) but reading about this pattern would help you to design your app more carefully.

There is an (old yet useful) [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29922/Weak-Events-in-C) on the matter. Again I am not saying you should use this pattern; I am saying studying this pattern will show you why static events are not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of scenario you can also use the [**Mediator**](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMediator.aspx) design pattern to subscribe and notify  "global" events.

```
Mediator.Subscribe("Login", callbackForLogin);

Mediator.Notify("Login", parameters);
```

You can use "WeakReference" when implementing this design pattern to avoid memory leaks (references not garbage-collected).

for example:
http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/using-mediator-to-communicate-between-user-controls-part-7/